# How to determine whether a directory is on an NFS mounted drive?

Tags: linux, nfs

How can I determine whether a given directory on a Linux machine is from an NFS mounted drive or not?

Comment: You can always look at the output of mount. It will list all the mounts on the system. You'll be able to tell if your folder is on one of the mounts based off the folder path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `df -t nfs <directory>`, which will produce output like

```
$ df /home/aland/ -t nfs
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
nfs_oscar:/home      1255425376 874128064 316496736  74% /home
```

if directory belogs to NFS mount, and nothing otherwise:

```
$ df /root/ -t nfs
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
```

Edit: simpler way: `df -T <directory>` (flag `-P` is used to disable pretty formatting to facilitate `tail`ing and `awk`ing):

```
$ df /home/aland/ -TP  | tail -n -1 | awk '{print $2}'
nfs
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `stat` utility with `-f` to say you're looking for information about the filesystem.

For example:

```
$ stat -f -c %T .
ext2/ext3
$ stat -f -c %T /sys
sysfs
$ stat -f -c %T /proc
proc
$ if [[ $(stat -f -c %T /proc) == proc ]] ; then echo Good ; fi
Good
```

(See the man page for the different formatting options, and sorry I don't have an NFS mount handy.)

Answer (score 1):

I would simple use the default tool `mountpoint`:

```
NAME
       mountpoint - see if a directory is a mountpoint

SYNOPSIS
       mountpoint [-d|-q] directory
```

Since you are talking specifically about `NFS`, this means you have also access to `showmount`, except this work the other way around (from a host instead of a directory):

```
NAME
       showmount - show mount information for an NFS server

SYNOPSIS
       showmount [ -adehv ] [ --all ] [ --directories ] [ --exports ] [ --help ] [ --version ] [ host ]
```